# ui-router Go creates double path element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am using UI-Router in my angular Meteor project.
When I am in route /search and want to relocate to /search/:term (for example /search/starwars) and I use in my controller

```
$state.go( 'private.search.feed', { term: 'starwars' } )
```

then it URL in my browser turns in to `/search/search/starwars` instead of `/search/starwars`.

My route setup (I have 2 layouts, hence the abstract views)

```
$stateProvider

  # abstract views / layout
  .state 'private',
    url: ''
    abstract: true
    views:
      'app':
        templateUrl: 'client/views/layouts/privateLayout.html'

  .state 'public',
    url: ''
    abstract: true
    views:
      'app':
        templateUrl: 'client/views/layouts/publicLayout.html'

  # end abstract views / layout

  .state 'private.home',
    url: '/'
    views:
      "container@private":
        templateUrl: 'client/views/home/home.html'


  .state 'private.search',
    url: '/search'
    views:
      "container@private":
        templateUrl:  'client/views/search/search.html'
        controller:   'searchCtrl'

  .state 'private.search.feed',
    url: '/search/:term'
    views:
      "container@private":
        templateUrl:  'client/views/search/feed/feed.html'
        controller:   'searchCtrl'
```

When I change the route to

```
.state 'private.searchFeed',
    url: '/search/:term'
    views:
      "container@private":
        templateUrl:  'client/views/search/feed/feed.html'
        controller:   'searchCtrl'
```

and call

```
$state.go( 'private.searchFeed', { term: 'starwars' } )
```

the url is correct.

I reckon I defined a child state in the first setup, but I don't understand why it would repeat `search` in the URL.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a *dot* in the name of a state indicates to `ui-router` that it is a *child state* of whatever state is defined by the *dotpath*. For example:

```
State 1: home (/home)
State 2: home.dashboard (/home/dashboard)
State 3: home.dashboard.settings (/home/dashboard/settings)
```

You cannot create a new state *State 4* called `home.dashboard.settings.save` whose route does not begin with the URL given to *State 3*, as *State 4*'s *dotpath* indicates that it should inherit from *State 3*.

**So you need to ensure that a URL for a child state does not repeat the URL of its parent:**

```
.state 'private.search.feed',
    url: '/:term'
```

Comment: To easy gents, thanks very much. I didn't get that part when I read the docs on ui-router, but now the parent, child, siblings diagram makes more sense :)

Answer (score 2):

You `private.search.feed` state url should be `'/:term'` because the URL of parent state gets inherited in state derived from it. As your derived state has to be like `/:term` will apparently become/accessible via `/search/:term`

**Code**

```
.state 'private.search.feed',
    url: '/:term'
    views:
      "container@private":
        templateUrl:  'client/views/search/feed/feed.html'
        controller:   'searchCtrl'
```

Comment: To easy gents, thanks very much. I didn't get that part when I read the docs on ui-router, but now the parent, child, siblings diagram makes more sense :)

Comment: @Mattijs Glad to help you..Feel free to accept answer..There are multiple options to accept.. :)